# How can I itrate through multiple dictionaries inside an array?[JSON]

Tags: json, swift

I have a JSON response and inside that response there is an array

```
"ItemList":[  
   {  
      "ItemInfoList":[  
         {  
            "Price":{  
               "basePrice":{  
                  "amount":{  
                     "currency":{  
                        "code":"INR"
                     },
                     "value":60
                  }
               },
               "Price":{  
                  "basePrice":{  
                     "amount":{  
                        "currency":{  
                           "code":"INR"
                        },
                        "value":55
                     }
                  },
                  "Price":{  
                     "basePrice":{  
                        "amount":{  
                           "currency":{  
                              "code":"INR"
                           },
                           "value":82
                        }
                     },

             }]
```

How can I get each of those values(60,55,82) from "value" ?
How do I itrate / map through the dictionary inside the ItemInfoList array?

By using

```
arr.append(ItemList[0].ItemInfoList[0].Price.basePrice.amount.value)
```

, I can append the first value to my array. How can I get the other values?(55 and 82)

Comment: try something like `let arr = itemList.map({ $0.itemInfoList.map({ $0.Price.basePrice.amount.value }) })`

Comment: Why would you mix **Upper Camel Case** & **Lower Camel Case**? Be consistent with variable identifiers. @Scriptable just showed you an example in the first comment. You should be able to slightly modify it according to your data structure.

Comment: @nayem is right, in swift you only really capitalize type names, the rest should be lower camel case. Whichever you choose you should be consistent with though

Comment: @Scriptable I didn't give the name, I used a decodable generator and it kinda put those names and I didn't bother changing them. It still says , no member, but right clicking and clicking jump to definition correctly takes to the object !

Comment: @Scriptable Please post your comment as an answer? So I can select it as the answer.

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
let arr = itemList.map({ $0.itemInfoList.map({ $0.Price.basePrice.amount.value }) })
```

This will loop through the arrays and return the required values giving you the required array result